# How to search for matches with optional special characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, search, apostrophe

I have a problem with a search query I am using my data contains names and information that has apostrophes in various forms (HTML encoded and actual).
So for example I would like an alternative to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE REPLACE(LastName,'''','') 
LIKE Replace('O''Brien,'''','')
```

This is just an example, what I want is a way where if someone types OBrien or O'Brien this will still work, I need to replace three versions of the character and the data is feed sourced and cannot be changed - what can be done to a query to allow for this kind of search to work.
I have Items with names which work this way which currently have many nested REPLACE functions and cannot seem to find something that will work this way, which is more efficient.
I am using MS SQL 2000 with ASP if that helps.

---

**Edit**

Here is the query that needs to match O'Brien or OBrien, this query does this but is too inefficient - it is joined by another for Item Names and FirstName (optional) for matching.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LastName,'&apos;',''),'&#39;',''),'''','') 
LIKE 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('%O&#39;Brien%','&apos;',''),'&#39;',''),'''','')
```

Comment: Why are you storing HTML entities in your database, instead of the *actual* characters?

Comment: The HTML entities come with the data source as this is from an external source which stores the data this way, maybe this could be replaced with the actual characters - that may solve the need for multiple replaces

Comment: Not having HTML in the database prevents all kinds of nasty headaches, not only this one. If you can do anything about it, normalize the HTML entities out of the data before storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stay correct and do this in SQL this is probably the best you can do

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 
LastName LIKE 'O%Brien' AND 
REPLACE(LastName,'''','') LIKE 'O''Brien'
```

You will still get table scans sometimes, due to poor selectivity.

The reason for the first where is to try to use an existing index.
The reason for the second match is to ensure that last names like ObbBrien do not match.

Of course the best thing to do would be not to need the ugly replace. This could be achieved in the app by storing an additional clean lastname column. Or in a trigger. Or in an indexed view.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE LastName LIKE Replace('O''Brien,'''','%')
```

This *should* allow it to use an index as you are not modifying the original column.

Comment: Note that in this specific instance it will most likely choose a full scan cause it may think its too expensive to pull all the records starting with O from the index. I agree this is probably the best you can do in a like query

Comment: Also, this is very risky for certain inputs eg: OohnoitsBrien will match as well!!!

Answer (score 1):

For pure SQL, the escaping is entirely unnecessary.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE LastName = 'O''Brien'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters instead of building the queries in code.

If you are using ADO you can use a syntax like this:

```
Dim cmd, rs, connect, intNumber
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = "your connectionstring"
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE LastName LIKE @LastName"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@LastName",,,,"O'Brien")
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

This should perform the query and insert the string O'Brien properly formatted for your database.

Using parameters ensures that all values are properly formatted and it also protects you against sql injection attacks.